# How to get the instance using Guice of a interface annotated by @ImplementedBy

Tags: java, guice

I am using an library which internally has a class

```
@ImplementedBy(MyClassImpl.class)
public interface MyClassInterface {
....
}
```

When Guice, how can get the instance of the MyClassImpl?

Do I have to create a binding:

```
bind(MyClassInterface.class).to(MyClassImpl.class);
```

in order to use it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to create a binding, although you can. If you do it will override the `@ImplementedBy` annotation.

You can get an instance of it via ordinary injection, e.g.

```
@Inject
public Client(MyClassInterface foo) {
  ...
}
```

or (if it's the top-level class):

```
injector.getInstance(MyClassInterface.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You either inject the interface:

```
@Inject
MyClassInterface myClass;
```

or you can use an injector to get an instance:

```
MyClassInterface myClass = injector.getInstance(MyClassInterface.class);
```

both will be injected with the MyClassImpl type.